# Akamai Rest Api's How to call from Asp.net Core HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient, akamai

Folks,

I am building a DNS management Api using Akamai. Their edgegrid signing example looks complex. How do I make Api calls to Akamai's Rest Api using Asp.Net core HttpClient interface.

Here is the section from their documentation i am interested in. It specifies everything but where do i supply the client secret, access token and client token? Should that be in the request headers?

[Akamai Api Definition for Create Recordset](https://developer.akamai.com/api/cloud_security/edge_dns_zone_management/v2.html#postzonerecordset)

```
POST /config-dns/v2/zones/{zone}/names/{name}/types/{type}

Sample: /config-dns/v2/zones/example.com/names/www.example.com/types/A

Content-Type: application/json


Request body:

{
    "name": "www.example.com",
    "type": "A",
    "ttl": 300,
    "rdata": [
        "10.0.0.2",
        "10.0.0.3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code that your wrote. The current outcome. The expected outcome. And exceptions with stacktraces.

Comment: The nuget might be out of date. I recommend grabbing the C# EdgeGrid library from GitHub which is always up-to-date. Link here: https://github.com/akamai/AkamaiOPEN-edgegrid-C-Sharp /Mike

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to set-up Akamai APIs with ASP.net. Sadly, we do not have an out-of-the-box integration available for this language. (You can find the other available languages here: https://developer.akamai.com/legacy/introduction/Open_Source.html).

You can use the HttpClient interface to make the HTTPS call. But you are correct, you will need to authenticate the request properly with Akamai EdgeGrid. You client token, client secret and access token need to be hashed with a timestamp to create an AuthorizationHeader. The code examples in other languages will take care of that for you, sadly no ASP.net though.

Alternatively, you could use the Akamai CLI (https://developer.akamai.com/cli/) and use the dns package to manage the zones for you. Let me know if that works for you.

/akamaimike

Comment: hi Mike, I placed follow up question here with command line, maybe you can help, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760324/akamai-rest-apis-use-with-net-core-and-command-line

Comment: also, should we still use this nuget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akamai.EdgeGrid.Auth/

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, if you want to receive streaming data, you might create your own api. You can use partially generating signed authHeader by using existing library. but if you have proxy server and ssl, you need to modify or create on top of the provided library.

Basic Implementation is like this.

1. get followings: host, client secrete, access token, client token
2. Generate signature-> this is where edgegrid library plays
   you can create your own.
   you need generate followings first
   a. UTC time:yyymmddThh:mi:ss+0000
   b. nonce: GUID (in java UUID.randomUID().toString())

signKey = base64_encode(sign(timestamp, client_secrete))
Authdata = GET {url including parameters} {algorithm like EG1-HMAC-SHA256} {client_token={val};access_token={val};timestamp={val};nonce={val}}
authHeader = base64_encode(sign(authData, signKey))

// discard {} when you apply value.

Use httpclient by using authHeader and parameters.

For Akamai Siem example, parameters are limit, from, to, offset combination.
first request use limit, from, to
then use limit, offeset for next request and loop until total return zero or event time in data is over "to" (it is stream data, so you have to enforce to stop).  offset has special character like ";" so you need url encoding when you use parameters in url and also you have to url encoded offset when you create authData.

About sing(), it signs data with key.  sign(data, key)
authdata and key should be converted to byte[]
in Java, use SecreKeySpec and Mac for generating signed output(byte[])with algorithm.

timstamp should be current otherwise if it is too old, it won't work.

You can start with postman and testing and then write code. I recommend to testing and developing so that you can debug easy.

-make sure generate signedData for authheader
-url in signedData needs parameters
-url is used to both authHeader generation and actual request
-offset must be urlencoded in authHeader generation.
-make sure your JVN enough memory for fetching data limit.
-filter data if you want to receive range of timed data. Akamai does not send exact boundary timed data.